# Use Node JS from php Elastic Beanstalk enviroment

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to use shell_exec to run a node app like that:

```
shell_exec(node app.js) ;
```

But I got an error:
sh: node: command not found

I have tried to install node js using confing file like that:

```
commands:
  01_node_install:
    # run this command from /tmp directory
    cwd: /tmp
    # don't run the command if node is already installed (file /usr/bin/node exists)
    test: '[ ! -f /usr/bin/node ] && echo "node not installed"'
    # install from epel repository
    # flag -y for no-interaction installation
    command: 'yum install -y nodejs --enablerepo=epel'
```

This was all of my env.config file but I don't see anything in the Elastic Beanstalk log related to that and the problem still exists.
How could I use Node JS from php environment !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration file is fine. Just make sure that **env.config** is inside **.ebextensions** folder in the root directory of your project.