# Deploying php + node js e-commerce application to elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an e-commerce backend in PHP(part of which is powered by node js) which is to be deployed in elastic beanstalk. Do I need to use Docker in elastic beanstalk or can I deploy directly to elastic beanstalk PHP environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I need to use Docker in elastic beanstalk or can I deploy directly to elastic beanstalk PHP environment?

Technically you don't need Docker. But, as sidenote, althought you can install and run node.js from php Elastic Beanstalk environment using `.ebextensions/env.config` like detailed in [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46329428/use-node-js-from-php-elastic-beanstalk-enviroment) depending on your setup docker might be better approach.